# How to separate the title of journal in first page, and second page begin with abstract in a manuscript for revision Elsevier

Tags: page-breaking, titles, abstract

The full names, full affiliation with country, and email addresses of every contributing author must be included in the title (authorship) page of the manuscript. The first page of the manuscript should contain the title of the paper, and the full name, full affiliation with country, and email address of every contributing author. The second page of the manuscript should begin with the paper abstract.

How can we separate the title on the first page of the manuscript and the second page begin with the abstract? Below is MWE for you :)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document} 
\title [mode = title]{Title:} 
\begin{abstract}
sdf fdg gdg 
\end{abstract} 
\maketitle
\section{Introduction} 
\bibliographystyle{model5-names}
\bibliography{cas-refs} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Put a `\newpage` between the end of the title stuff and the start of the abstract.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it is not working. i am using \documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc} class for Elsevier.

Comment: I have not come across the `cas-sc` class before. If it isn't producing what Elsevier are asking for is there another one to be used? It would have been helpful if you had provided an MWE (from `documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we could compile that showed your problem --- just enough to produce the first two (problem) pages.

Comment: Here is MWE: \documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}
\usepackage{natbib}
\def\tsc#1{\csdef{#1}{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}\xspace}}
\begin{document}
\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}
\shorttitle{XYZ}
\shortauthors{L. a et~al.}
\title [mode = title]{Title:}              \author[1]{L}[type=editor]
\cormark[1]
\ead{x@s}
\begin{abstract}sdf fdg gdg
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\bibliographystyle{model5-names}
\bibliography{cas-refs}
\end{document}

Comment: I am not going to spend time trying to rewrite the code in your comment into an MWE, probably mistyping several items. I suggested that you edited your question to include an MWE but you did not do that. Please help yourself by helping others. --- GOM

Comment: I have provided a "don't know" answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is: I DON'T KNOW.

I tried your MWE, for which thank you, and fiddled around a bit with it, ending up with:

```
% casprob.tex  SE 594143

\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document} 
\title [mode = title]{Title:} 
\maketitle
\newpage
%\begin{abstract}
%sdf fdg gdg 
%\end{abstract} 
%\maketitle
\section{Introduction} 
\bibliographystyle{model5-names}
\bibliography{cas-refs} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that there is no abstract in the MWE but still the ABSTRACT title appears. This is must be an integral part of the class code or of some package code that the class calls in.

If you really want your abstract on the second page I suggest that you contact Elsevier and ask them how to do it.